# Espaço em Branco selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf

gostaria de saber se é possível remover um campo em branco no selectOneMenu, tenho o seguinte caso, possuo um selectOneMenu que exibe vários nomes, alguns nomes que não quero que apareçam eu utilizei o .replace("nome",""), só que agora o selectOneMenu meio que pula uma linha onde tinha o nome que eu dei o .replace, como faço agora para remover esta linha em branco ?

abaixo é o método que estou utilizando para listar no selectOneMenu ele pega o nome dos arquivos que estão em um diretório

```
public ArrayList<String> SearchFileStop (String p) throws SQLException{

    DirControle dc = new DirControle();
    File file = new File(String.valueOf(dc.selectedDir_CB()).replace("[", "").replace("]","")+"\\"+p);
       File afile[] = file.listFiles();
       int i = 0;
       for (int j = afile.length; i< j; i++){
           File arq = afile[i];

          listaFiles.add(arq.getName().replace("datasulDescargaBancos.bat","").replace(" ",""));
       }

       return listaFiles;
    }
```

o meu bean

```
public ArrayList<String> selectedFile(String arq) throws SQLException{return sdir.SearchFile(arq);}
```

O SelectOneMenu, nesse caso o problema esta no segundo:

Para:

```
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="selecione" itemValue=""/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{dir_controle.selectedDs()}"  />
                                <p:ajax listener="#{scripts.listener}" update="arquivo" /> 

                            </h:selectOneMenu>

                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="title4">Banco:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <h:selectOneMenu id="arquivo" value="#{scripts.arquivo}" style="width: 200px">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione"/> 
                                <f:selectItems  value="#{dir_controle.selectedFile(scripts.pasta)}" />

                            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Os dados estão vindo do banco? Para lhe ajudar melhor, sugiro que poste os códigos que você está usando.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e poste o código nela, fica mais legível por favor.

Comment: editei ve se esta mais claro agora

Comment: Poste também a sua página xhtml.

Comment: postei espero que esteja mais claro

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, o problema não está no `jsf`, mas sim na sua lógica ao popular a lista de `String`.

Se você precisa que, caso o nome do arquivo fique totalmente vazio, não seja incluido em `listaFiles`, é só não inserir em `listaFiles`.

```
listaFiles.add(arq.getName().replace("datasulDescargaBancos.bat","").replace(" ",""));
```

Na linha acima, você não se importa com isso. O correto seria fazer algo assim:

```
String nomeAhSerInseridoEmLista = arq.getName().replace("datasulDescargaBancos.bat","").replace(" ","");
if(!nomeAhSerInseridoEmLista.isEmpty()) {
    listaFiles.add(nomeAhSerInseridoEmLista);
}
```

Comment: Entendi fiz dessa maneira e funcionou, se puder me tirar outra duvida nessa mesma parte tem como eu ocultar a string inteira verificando se ela tem um pedaço da de uma palavra nela, por exemplo datasulDescargaBancos.bat  ocultar se tiver Descarga na palavra

Comment: Tenta utilizar `nomeAhSerInseridoEmLista.contains("descarga")`, talvez funcione. Ai vai de acordo com sua lógica, se quiser incluir ela ou não na lista.